# Github & Release Branch Showing diffs that shouldn't be there

Tags: git, github, pull-request

We are trying to create a workflow with PRs to continuously release new versions of our application.

I created a repo as an example of what's happening. https://github.com/austinbv/test-pr

The general workflow we are attempting:

1. Developers work in a feature branch (https://github.com/austinbv/test-pr/tree/flowthrough)
2. Developer pushes Feature branch and creates a PR from Feature branch into `master` (https://github.com/austinbv/test-pr/pull/1)
3. Feature branch gets merged into master (https://github.com/austinbv/test-pr/pull/1)
4. After a while, we cut a release by creating a PR from `master` into a `prod` (https://github.com/austinbv/test-pr/pull/2)
5. `master` is merged into `prod` (https://github.com/austinbv/test-pr/pull/2)
6. Rinse and repeat!

When we create merges into prod from master we always see merge conflicts, and ALL the commits that have happened on master since prod was created are applied.

You can see that here (https://github.com/austinbv/test-pr/pull/5).

Things that seem off:

- The PR shows too many commits being merged https://github.com/austinbv/test-pr/pull/5/commits
- The PR Shows more changes than need to be applied https://github.com/austinbv/test-pr/pull/5/files
- The diff view on github shows the correct diff https://github.com/austinbv/test-pr/compare/master..prod
- The create PR shows the incorrect diff https://github.com/austinbv/test-pr/compare/master...prod
- All merges and rebases work as expected if I use `git` locally to do it

Any opinions on what we are doing or if we are misusing git/github are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you observe is definitely caused by the way the Pull Requests in your project have been "merged" (I put this word between quotes because it seems no merge actually took place).

To be more precise, GitHub provides **three ways to integrate a pull request** in another branch, cf. the following screenshot taken from the [official GitHub documentation](https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/merging-a-pull-request):

[image: merging-a-pull-request]

Among the three possible ways to integrate a pull request:

- Create a merge commit
- Squash and merge
- Rebase and merge

only the first one leads to a [true merge](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#_true_merge) and creates a so-called **merge commit**, that is a commit with ≥2 parents.

The other strategies actually rely on the [`git rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) command (squash being a variant of `git rebase -i …`), which has the following "drawbacks":

- `git rebase` is a destructive operation: it changes the **SHA1** of the rebased commits and it is possible that **some or all of the rebased commits don't compile anymore** after the rebase! (while the initial commits did compile);
- as the SHA1 of the rebased commits changes, Git often cannot see these commits are related to their initial counterpart in the other branch. Hence the spurious, unexpected **merge conflicts** you get when attempting to create PR #5 from `master` to `prod`;
- finally, when you observe the graph of the commits, you can't see anymore after a rebase or a squash, what is the exact "history" of the contribution integrated by the PR, given that the history tweaked by `git rebase` has been made "linear", cf. the screenshots below produced by `gitk prod` then `gitk --all` on your example project:

  > `gitk prod`

  [image: gitk prod]

  > [`gitk --all`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitk#Documentation/gitk.txt---all)

  [image: gitk --all]

  while a standard, `git merge`-based history would look like a "directed graph", cf. e.g. the screenshot below taken from [this older SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49581009/9164010):

  > `gitk` in another example project

  [image: gitk master]

so in this context, you may want to systematically use the *Create a merge commit* GitHub PR strategy, which seems more adapted to your 2-step workflow (merge in `master`, then merge in `prod`).

As an aside, this workflow looks quite similar to the so-called [Git flow](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/), where the two main branches are called (`develop`, `master`) instead of (`master`, `prod`).

Comment: Hey @ErikMD - First of all thanks for the awesome answer. Well formatted and great. Saddly I have created repos and tested merging PRs that use ALL different forms of merge. I figured a rebase was likely the worst and our preferred is a `Squash and Merge`

The odd thing to me is that we show diffs - that are not true. That's where I think github may have a cache issue

Comment: Hi @austinbv, actually Squash-and-merge is just a variant of Rebase-and-merge, so you'll get the same drawbacks with Squash-and-merge as those of git-rebase I mentioned in my answer, plus the fact the individual history of each PR containing several commits is lost. I'm sure there's no "cache issue" in GitHub: basically, Squash-and-merge can be OK if the features are integrated once (in master) but if it's done twice (in master then prod), **you'll always get unexpected conflicts if you Squash-and-merge the 2nd PRs to prod**. *So you should rather use a true merge, at least for these 2nd PRs…*

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Developers work in a feature branch (https://github.com/austinbv/test-pr/tree/flowthrough)
> 2. Developer pushes Feature branch and creates a PR from Feature branch into master (https://github.com/austinbv/test-pr/pull/1)

You left out 1a: Developer pulls `master` and rebases feature branch onto `master` just before pushing.

If you did that, you would not get all this extra history, because each branch merged onto `master` would have diverged at the top of `master`.

Comment: regarding the workflow mentioned by the OP, if the feature branches are independent features, it is not necessary a priori to pull master or rebase onto origin/master (but it is required in case of conflict, of course)

Comment: regarding the unexpected conflict mentioned by the OP, maybe this comes from the fact that the commit `Add something to the readme (#1)` has not been merged by PR #2 : master→prod, but rebased into commit `Add something to the readme (#1) (#2)`, so PR #5 : master→prod proposes to integrate again this commit `Add something to the readme (#1)`…